# Camel rest response using ftl

Tags: rest, apache-camel

I have a camel rest route takes produces/consumes json after its due operation. Now, I want the json response to be created using FTL but I am not able to do it.

Here's my code:

```
rest("/").bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto).description("Search for CAF").consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")
                .post("/search/cam")
                .type(CAMRequestDTO.class)
                .outType(CAMResponseDTO.class)
                .route().routeId("search-caf")
                .process(camSearchPreProcessor)
                .bean(camSearchService, "getCAMDetails(${body})")
                .streamCaching()
                .to("freemarker:file:/temp/ftls/camSearch.ftl")//problem
                .end().endRest();
```

I'm unable to use ftl template here as it throws:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found for name "/temp/ftls/camSearch.ftl".
The name was interpreted by this TemplateLoader: org.apache.camel.component.freemarker.FreemarkerComponent$1@4b35d31f.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct url requires a **double** slash:

```
 .to("freemarker:file://temp/ftls/camSearch.ftl")
```

Even if the most correct is a **triple** slash. 
Indeed the complete syntax is "file://host/path" and the host can be omitted for localhost. This would result in your case in

```
"file:///temp/ftls/camSearch.ftl"
```

Comment: triple did it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try having only freemarker and path to ftl. Like this

```
freemarker:temp/ftls/camSearch.ftl
```